# <img> is blurry when viewed in tumblr post, otherwise looks crisp?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm using tumblr. I've inserted an image, html looks like:

```
<img height="320" src="foo.png" width="400" />
```

My image really is that exact size, width(400), height(320). It has text in it, and looks crisp if I visit the url of the image directly (or locally on my machine).

In the tumblr post however, the image is quite blurry. It is indeed 400 pixels wide in screen pixels, but looks like there's some weird compression being applied possibly through some css attribute on the  tag that I'm not aware of?

Anything I can check to see what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to this happening live, or maybe a screenshot? What is the link to the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure whats the problem but you can try putting the `img` inside a `div` and fix the size of `div` using style instead of `img`. something like

```
<div style="height:320px;width:400px;">
  <img src="foo.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving the image a height with css for example

```
<img style="width: 400px; height: 320px;" src="foo.png" />
```

or dont even use an img tag use a div for example

```
<div style="background: url(foo.png); width: 400px; height: 320px;"></div>
```

Comment: No, please don't. You're supposed to specify the width and height on an image so that the browser will reserve that amount of space for the image while it is being downloaded. Also, making it a background of a division removes its semantic meaning. As well, backgrounds do not show up when printing pages in a majority of cases.